# Given a DOI, how can I programmatically obtain all the relevant dates from a paper?

Tags: doi

I have to collect the relevant dates (date submited, revised, accepted, published) from a large amount of papers. I would like to do this using R but I could adapt to any other suggested method. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm with Crossref's tech support team.  I can speak to what's possible via the Crossref metadata APIs. (with the caveat that Crossref is only one DOI Registration Agency out of several, though most DOIs for scholarly publications are registered with us)

Our metadata schema allows publishers to supply publication history with any or all of those dates, but it's entirely optional.  So, you're not going to find that kind of metadata for every DOI you query.

When publishers do include the publication history data, it'll look like this in the JSON output from our REST API, using the DOI [10.1128/mBio.02819-18](https://dx.doi.org/10.1128/mBio.02819-18) as an example

```
"assertion": [
{
"value": "2018-12-15",
"order": 0,
"name": "received",
"label": "Received",
"group": {
"name": "publication_history",
"label": "Publication History"
}
},
{
"value": "2019-01-24",
"order": 1,
"name": "accepted",
"label": "Accepted",
"group": {
"name": "publication_history",
"label": "Publication History"
}
},
{
"value": "2019-03-05",
"order": 2,
"name": "published",
"label": "Published",
"group": {
"name": "publication_history",
"label": "Publication History"
}
}
```

query via https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1128/mBio.02819-18

or like this in the xml API

```
<assertion group_label="Publication History" group_name="publication_history" label="Received" name="received" order="0">2018-12-15</assertion>
<assertion group_label="Publication History" group_name="publication_history" label="Accepted" name="accepted" order="1">2019-01-24</assertion>
<assertion group_label="Publication History" group_name="publication_history" label="Published" name="published" order="2">2019-03-05</assertion>
```

query via [http://doi.crossref.org/search/doi?pid={your-email-address}&format=unixsd&doi=10.1128/mBio.02819-18](http://doi.crossref.org/search/doi?pid=%7Byour-email-address%7D&format=unixsd&doi=10.1128/mBio.02819-18)

some other examples of DOIs with publication history metadata are
10.9758/cpn.2014.12.1.8
and
10.5155/eurjchem.13.1.iii-vi.2233

And you can find our API documentation at [api.crossref.org](http://api.crossref.org/).

There may be other sources which map DOIs to publication history dates more thoroughly than what the publishers opt to include in Crossref.  If so, I'd be interested in hearing about them!